# How can I render a toon character's head to always be visible in front of his body?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Currently, I am working on a cartoon that will be modeled in 3D and rendered into 2D. The art style we want to go with isn't technically accurate within 3D space. The character has no neck and his head always appears in front of his body whether in front view or side view.

Does anyone know of a way that I can make the head object always visible in front of the character's body object and only through one layer of the character's body? Sort of like how Freestyle has QI range for rendering lines behind a certain number of faces. I want to do that, but for meshes.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3L_xnZSg2i-WkVVcTh6UlkzMVE)

Reference images:
[image: reference images]

Answer (score -1):

you could make it a flat object with a constrain to always  point it to the camera